# how to use iOS functions with two version

Tags: ios, objective-c

As an iOS developer, we always need to catch up with iOS updates. Sometimes the old version of a specific method is deprecated in high version of iOS.

However we need to support multiple versions' devices, since our users use different version iOS. So we need to implement the new version while we still need to keep the old version. However, when compile the app. The warning for using the new version is really bothering the developer. Here is the case.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
    // iOS 10 +
    [application openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
} else {
    // iOS 9
    [application openURL:url];
}
```

Here the [application openURL:url] is always give me a warning, How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: You won't get any warning if you only use the older API and your deployment target is set to the older version of iOS.

Comment: As a wise software wizard once said - IGNORE THE WARNINGS!

Comment: @GeneCode No one wise said "ignore the warnings". That's terrible advice.

Comment: TBH, many warnings in XCode can be ignored.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objective-C**

I just use statement

`#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"`

before using any deprecated API's to suppress warnings.

In your case code will be

```
    if ([UIApplication respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
        // iOS 10 +
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        // iOS 9
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

The best way to support multiple version SDK API's in swift is to use `available` attribute.

```
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason for this. If there is a deprecation warning for the use of `openURL:` then that means the deployment target is set to iOS 10 or later. And if that is the case then the app doesn't support iOS 9 so there is no reason for the `if/else`. Simply use the new API and make no attempt to use the deprecated API. If the deployment target is changed to iOS 9 or earlier, the warning will go away. But even then, you don't **need** the `if/else`. You can keep using the old API and there won't be any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

If u find  warring related deprecate , and it belongs to clang or GCC you can better to use macros (Availability.h).

```
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
        // iOS 10 +
        [application openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        // iOS 9
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        [application openURL:url];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

    }
```

To more warning related ref :http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/

Comment: I think 10 times before clicking on the link you provided... Viruses are everywhere...